# Error al crear una tabla en mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola gente del grupo soy de Argentina. Estoy tratando de agregar todas la provincias y localidades de Argentina en mi base de datos mysql workbench.
Cuando creo la tabla provincias me la crea bien:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `provincias`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `provincias` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`provincia` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

Pero cuando quiero crear la tabla localidades me tira este error:

```
CREATE TABLE `localidad` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`provincia_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`codigopostal` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
INDEX `fk_localidad_provincia_idx` (`provincia_id` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_localidad_provincia`
FOREIGN KEY (`provincia_id` )
REFERENCES `provincia` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

[image: Error]

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viendo tu codigo aun no me qeda claro donde esta la falla, pero si estas referenciando `foreign keys` procura reoordenar la creacion de tablas, dada que si una tabla no esta creada te dara error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario amigo! ya lo solucione y publique la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Gente ya lo solucione. Cambie mi código, así me quedo.
Tabla provincia:

```
CREATE TABLE `provincia` (
`id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`codigo31662` CHAR(4) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `codigo31662_UNIQUE` (`codigo31662` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Así me quedo la tabla localidades:

```
CREATE TABLE `localidad` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`provincia_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`codigopostal` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
INDEX `fk_localidad_provincia_idx` (`provincia_id` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_localidad_provincia`
FOREIGN KEY (`provincia_id` )
REFERENCES `provincia` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```